# Computing 7-day retention numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with two columns--date and id. I'd like to calculate for each date the number of id's on that date which reappear on a later date within 7 days. If I were doing this in postgres, it would look something like:

```
SELECT df1.date, COUNT(DISTINCT df1.id)
  FROM df df1 INNER JOIN df df2
    ON df1.id = df2.id AND
       df2.date BETWEEN df1.date + 1 AND df1.date + 7
GROUP BY df1.date;
```

What is problematic for me is how to translate this statement into pandas in a way that is fast and idiomatic and etc.

I've already tried for one-day retention by simply creating a lagged column and merging the original with the lagged dataframe. This certainly works. However, for seven-day retention I would need to create 7 dataframes and merge them together. That's not reasonable, as far as I'm concerned. (Especially because I'd also like to know 30-day numbers.)

(I should also point out that my research led me to https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2996, which indicates a merge behavior that **does not work** on my install (pandas 0.14.0) which fails with error message `TypeError: Argument 'values' has incorrect type (expected numpy.ndarray, got Series)`. So there appears to be some sort of advanced merge/join behavior which I clearly don't know how to activate.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, I think you can do it with a `groupby/apply`. It's a bit tricky. So I think you have data like the following:

```
>>> df

        date  id    y
0  2012-01-01   1  0.1
1  2012-01-03   1  0.3
2  2012-01-09   1  0.4
3  2012-01-12   1  0.0
4  2012-01-14   1  0.2
5  2012-01-16   1  0.4
6  2012-01-01   2  0.2
7  2012-01-02   2  0.1
8  2012-01-03   2  0.4
9  2012-01-04   2  0.6
10 2012-01-09   2  0.7
11 2012-01-10   2  0.4
```

I'm going to create rolling forward count within an 'id' group of the number of times that id shows up in the next 7 days including the current day:

```
def count_forward7(g):
    # Add column to the datframe so I can set date as the index
    g['foo'] = 1

    # New dataframe with daily frequency, so 7 rows = 7 days
    # If there are no gaps in the dates you don't need to do this
    x = g.set_index('date').resample('D')

    # Do Andy Hayden Method for a forward looking rolling windows
    # reverses the series and then reverses back the answer
    fsum = pd.rolling_sum(x[::-1],window=7,min_periods=0)[::-1]
    return pd.DataFrame(fsum[fsum.index.isin(g.date)].values,index=g.index)


>>> df['f7'] = df.groupby('id')[['date']].apply(count_forward7)
>>> df

        date  id    y  f7
0  2012-01-01   1  0.1   2
1  2012-01-03   1  0.3   2
2  2012-01-09   1  0.4   3
3  2012-01-12   1  0.0   3
4  2012-01-14   1  0.2   2
5  2012-01-16   1  0.4   1
6  2012-01-01   2  0.2   4
7  2012-01-02   2  0.1   3
8  2012-01-03   2  0.4   3
9  2012-01-04   2  0.6   3
10 2012-01-09   2  0.7   2
11 2012-01-10   2  0.4   1
```

Now if you want to now "calculate for each date the number of id's on that date which reappear on a later date within 7 days" just count for each date where f7 > 1:

```
>>> df['bool_f77'] = df['f7'] > 1
>>> df.groupby('date')['bool_f77'].sum()


2012-01-01    2
2012-01-02    1
2012-01-03    2
2012-01-04    1
2012-01-09    2
2012-01-10    0
2012-01-12    1
2012-01-14    1
2012-01-16    0
```

Or Something like the following:

```
>>> df.query('f7 > 1').groupby('date')['date'].count()

date
2012-01-01    2
2012-01-02    1
2012-01-03    2
2012-01-04    1
2012-01-09    2
2012-01-12    1
2012-01-14    1
```